# Delete letter spacing in a regular text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with lot of rows with letter spacing, i.e.

```
cat test.txt
Some word here: T h e Q u i c k B r o w n F o x J u m p s O v e r T h e L a z y D o g
Some doggerel: J a c k A n d J i l l W e n t U p T h e H i l l
```

I ask some regular expression to apply to this text file to delete spacing between characters, with some command line tool in Linux.

```
cat result.txt
Some word here: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
Some doggerel: Jack And Jill Went Up The Hill
```

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried? what is the word delimiter?

Comment: Also, (might be a typo on your part but) why is there a space after `Some word here: ` but no space after `Some doggerel:` in result.txt?

Comment: How could be possible that sed, or awk, are able to discriminate the space between `J` and `u` (in `Jumps`), that is to be removed from the space between `x` and `J` (`Fox Jumps`) that is to be preserved? TL;DR with the tools you mentioned your task is impossible.

Comment: @gboffi I'm guessing its the spaces before capital letters which should be preserved. But OP should be more explicit. Also, I think it's possible with `sed`, but again would depend on OP's actual requirements. 

Comment: @TrebuchetMS  Ooops, I stand corrected.  If this is what they want, it can be done...

Comment: Keyword is "if". ;-)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS: excuse me, it's a typo.

Comment: In same row, I have normal text (i.e. without spacing between characters) and letter-spacing-text (with space between characters)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS: i would like to preserve space before capital letters, if it's possible and it's not particulary difficult.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is what was divined by [TrebuchetMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239789/trebuchetms) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791672/delete-letter-spacing-in-a-regular-text-file#comment94434422_53791672), it's not difficult using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: '{gsub(/ /,"",$2); gsub(/[A-Z]/," &",$2) ; print $1":"$2}' file.txt
```

The one-line program ① split a line on `:`, ② erases all the spaces after the `:`, ③ puts a space in front of each capital letter (also in front of the first one) and ④ prints the concatenation of `$1` (what precedes the `:`), a `:` and 
`$2`, that is, the modified second part.

Comment: In some locales `A-Z` includes most lower case letters because they are ordered as `aAbBcC...zZ` or similar rather than `abc...zABC...Z`. Use the character class `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned in the comments that you could use `sed` for this. After trying it out, I lost hope in `sed` since I couldn't get lookarounds to work in their regexes. Apparently, the `perl` command can parse regexes with lookarounds. If you have the `perl` command, you can try this

```
perl -pe 's/ ([a-z])(?= |$)/\1/g' file.txt
```

or

```
cat file.txt | perl -pe 's/ ([a-z])(?= |$)/\1/g'
```

---

#### What in the world does this fence post mean?

The `perl` option `-e` tells the `perl` command to accept a script (that's the monstrous regex you see right after it) and `-p` will loop the script around the file. (I'm no perl expert, so I need someone to double check this, I only looked at `perl -h` for help.)

Now the regex.

The `s/<match>/<replace>/g` follows `sed`'s syntax. It'll `s`earch `g`lobally for the `<match>` and substitute it with the `<replace>`.

Here, the match was `([a-z])(?= |$)`, which tells `perl` to match places with spaces followed by a lower-case letter (`([a-z])`, where `[a-z]` denotes the set of characters to match, and `()` denotes a capture group, used in the `<replace>` section).

**And** to make sure that what follows is either a space or the end of the line (`(?= |$)`), that's the [positive] lookahead I was referring to before. The vertical bar implies "or". Thus, the lookahead will search for a space () "or" the end of the line (`$`). The lookahead ensures the correct match while not including the space/end in the match.

The replace was `\1`, which will replace the match with the **first** capture group. In this case, the capture group is whatever lower-case letter was matched.

#### Why this regex works

If you look at the first line of your text file:

```
Some word here: T h e Q u i c k B r o w n F o x J u m p s O v e r T h e L a z y D o g
```

We only want to match **lower-case letters**, which have a space after them, i.e. `a-z`. If we **only** match `a-z`, that will include `Some`, `word`, and `here`. So we match lower-case letters, with spaces at the front and back. We remove the first space by matching it, by only replacing the letter, dropping the space.

#### Limitations of this regex

If your file had

```
Lol a word here: T h e Q u i c k B r o w n F o x J u m p s O v e r T h e L a z y D o g
```

then the output would include:

```
Lola word here: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
```

not as accurate as [gboffi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791920/10239789) in that it matches *after* the colon, but still regexes are a short hack ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Further Reading: [Reference: What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r ':a;s/^(.*: .*) ([[:lower:]])/\1\2/;ta' file
```

Replace all cases of a space followed by a lower-case character by a the lower-case character following a `:` in the current line. This solution works its way back along the line until it fails when all cases have been catered for.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$2=gensub(/ ([^[:upper:]])/,"\\1","g",$2)}1' file
Some word here: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
Some doggerel: Jack And Jill Went Up The Hill
```

with any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {gsub(/ /,"",$2); gsub(/[[:upper:]]/," &",$2)}1' file
Some word here: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
Some doggerel: Jack And Jill Went Up The Hill
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more variant using Perl

```
$ cat peter.txt
Some word here: T h e Q u i c k B r o w n F o x J u m p s O v e r T h e L a z y D o g
Some doggerel: J a c k A n d J i l l W e n t U p T h e H i l l

$ perl -F":" -lane ' $F[1]=~s/ //g; $F[1]=~s/([A-Z])/ \1/g; print "$F[0]:$F[1]" ' peter.txt
Some word here: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
Some doggerel: Jack And Jill Went Up The Hill
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solve by many different way. The easiest way I can think of is just remove blank before lower case. I have tried using SED as [TrebuchetMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53792558/2682158) mentioned "SED didn't have lookarounds in their regexes"

```
echo "T h e Q u i c k B r o w n F o x J u m p s O v e r T h e L a z y D o g" |  sed 's/[[:blank:]]\([[:lower:]]\)/\1/g'
```

Output: The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
[image]

Comment: You missed the one thing that makes it difficult to do with sed which is that the substitutions must only happen in the substring after the first `:`. Try your suggestion with the **actual** sample input to see how it fails.